# How to output a .js file without using .html or a script tag

Tags: javascript, html

[image: 1]

Here is my javascript code with the file name .js I cannot seem to output my document.write using only this. I can do it by turning it into a .html file and enclose the codes with `<script>`. I would like to have an output without changing the file and just keep it in .js, how do I do it?

```
document.write("<b>A. Sales Problem</b><br><br>");

var productProfitArray = [
{"Product A": -75},
{"Product B": -70},
{"Product C": 98},  // Highest sales profit
{"Product D": 5},   // Profit nearest to 0
{"Product E": -88}, // Lowest sales profit
{"Product F": 29}
];

function topProduct(productProfitArray) {
  if (toString.call(productProfitArray) !== "[object Array]")
    return false;
  return Math.max.apply(null, productProfitArray.map(o => Object.values(o)[0]));
}


function bottomProduct(productProfitArray) {
  if (toString.call(productProfitArray) !== "[object Array]")
    return false;
  return Math.min.apply(null, productProfitArray.map(o => Object.values(o)[0]));
}

function zeroProfitProduct(productProfitArray) {
  const zero = 0;
  return productProfitArray.map(o => Object.values(o)[0]).reduce((a, b) => {
    return Math.abs(b - zero) < Math.abs(a - zero) ? b : a;
  });
}

var topProductValue = topProduct(productProfitArray);
var bottomProductValue = bottomProduct(productProfitArray);
var zeroProfitProductValue = zeroProfitProduct(productProfitArray);

document.write('Highest sales profit is:  ' + topProductValue + '<br>');
document.write('Lowest sales profit is:  ' + bottomProductValue + '<br>');
document.write('Profit nearest to 0 is:  ' + zeroProfitProductValue);
```

Comment: this is run in a browser, right? so how does the browser know what kind of file it is and what to do with it, if you don't tell him?

Comment: Please post code, not images of code

Comment: added, like i said i do not want to turn this into html and show output with that .js file

Comment: Without any HTML, there is no `document` - that is created by the HTML parser. Thus, also no `document.write` without a `document`. **So what are you asking, exactly?**

Comment: i guess an alternate code for document.write to show without using HTML

Answer (score 0):

You could have a paragraph element

```
    <p id = "highestsalesprofit"></p>
```

element in your HTML and then use the following to get the element and add your text to ii

```
    document.getElementById('highestsalesprofit').innerHTML = 'Highest sales profit is: ' + topProductValue + '<br>'
```